# Deconfiguration of the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable (irreparable)

Tags: django, config, ubuntu-18.04

The fact is that I have a VPS in Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 18.04. I installed everything necessary starting with the typical apt update and upgrade, then pip, virtualenvwrapper, django and postgresql, started with runserver and tried in the browser the django and django-admin test page, all perfect for a few days.

After a few days, I upgraded my system again with apt update and upgrade, and the django application stopped working, with the error **"You must either define the variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable or call settings.configure () before accessing settings. "**

I have tried many things without finding the solution; I have reinstalled virtualenvwraper, django, virtual environments and project, but it still does not work as before.
I have also tried to assign the variable manually with  **export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = settings** and it says that the module can not be found.

Any idea of ​​what has happened to my system?
I would like to try all the possibilities before deleting the droplet and reinstalling everything.

Comment: What's your project structure? Normally you might require that setting if you have a non-standard settings setup.

Comment: The project structure is standard, it is the structure that django creates with **django-admin startproject**. This default structure gives me variable error. Something that worked the first time.

Comment: Please state *exactly* what you were doing when you got that message.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my NOVICE FAILURE, accustomed to working at local, I forgot to assign the IP of my server at the end of **python manage.py runserver 15.15.15.15:8000** Sorry, I'm sorry, I'm sorry.

But I have learned a good lesson; if we use django-admin we must assign the variable **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** beforehand, something that I could not achieve with **export** because it gave me errors as I mentioned in the other posts (it does not matter). Then it is better to use **python manage.py** which automatically assigns this variable for us.